# Material-UI + React : Card cannot expand with expander

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, material-ui

I have a simple Card component that I copied from the material-ui's website.

I'm trying to implement that in my code. When I click on the CardHeader, it would not expand.

This is my Component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

const CardExample = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <Card expanded={true}>
            <CardHeader
              title="Without Avatar"
              subtitle="Subtitle"
              actAsExpander={true}
              showExpandableButton={true}
            />
            <CardText expandable={true}>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
              Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
              Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
            </CardText>
            <CardActions expandable={true}>
                <FlatButton label="Action1" />
                <FlatButton label="Action2" />
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
)

export default CardExample;
```

And I've imported it to my container here :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LogoBig from '../components/logobig';
import CardExample from '../components/cardexample';

export default class Completed extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="popup completed main-container">
                <div className="logobar">
                    <div className="logo">
                        <LogoBig />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mainpanel">
                    <CardExample />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I've implemented it just as the docs in material-ui's site, but the expander does nothing.

Please help me with this. Is there anything wrong with the way I import the component? Or something else?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't look to weird to me. Are you getting any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: No errors on the console.
I read from various google searches, that I need to implement 'react-tap-event-plugin'. Is this a dependency for material-ui?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, material-ui requires **react-tap-event-plugin** for some components handling click actions (like expandable Card or IconMenu). This dependency is promised to be removed in the future, but for now you need to:

1. Install the react-tap-event-plugin via npm with the --save flag
2. Import & invoke the plugin somewhere in the app initialization code like this:

```html
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: Yes, It worked when I include the injectTapEventPlugin in my index.js.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be this:

```
<Card expanded={true}>
```

You've bound your expanded value permanently to a constant 'true' instead of bounding it to a component state:

```
<Card expanded={this.state.cardExpanded}>
```

You probably need to make a two way data binding. Take look at "Controlled Components" here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

This is all I can tell from the top of my head. I know it's not a fully functional answer, but I don't have the environment to test it for you, and I never really used this particular m-ui component. Still, I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I edited the code with expanded={true} for testing so it would force the card to be expanded